# Dropdown list in every cell in a column (Excel) + autocomplete and scrolling

Tags: excel, autocomplete, dropdown

So I want this.. But I also want that dropdown list to be in every cell in a column, like in data validation and not just ONE dropdown list that you can move around.

So is it possible to put like.. For every cell in a column make a dropdown list in that cell and lock it? And then put the codes that people have answered in other topics in there and make it happen when it comes to autocomplete and mouse scrollwheel?

Comment: It doesn't sound like much in 2019 but it's not that easy to acheive.  To get a very basic auto complete you'll need to use an active x combo box object.  The reason why most people use 1 dropdown that moves around is becuase the user can only edit 1 cell at a time so it's easier than filling the sheet full of dropdowns.

Comment: Ok, well. Then I guess I could make it work with 1 dropdown, but select which cell that value is gonna be inserted in?

Like, pick the cell, click dropdown and pick value, then next cell.. ?